# fprintf(fp, "%c",10) not behaving as expected

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
    FILE* fp = fopen("img.ppm","w");
    fprintf(fp,"%c", 10);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

for some reason that I am unable to uncover, this writes 2 bytes to the file: "0x0D 0x0A" while the behaviour I would expect is for it to just write "0x0A" which is 10 in decimal. It seems to work fine with every single other value between 0 and 255 included, it just writes one byte to the file. I am completely lost, any help?

Comment: try `FILE* fp = fopen("img.ppm","wb");`

Comment: Using `"wb"` is the solution if you want to write a single `\xA` byte to a binary file. If you want to create a text file, that two-character sequence is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Windows C runtime library, newline characters are written as `\r\n`, or `13 10`.  Which is `0x0D 0x0A`.  This is the only character that's *actually* written as two characters (by software compiled using the Windows toolchain).

You need to open the file with `fopen("img.ppm","wb")` to write binary.

Comment: It is not a windows issue, it is a compiler issue.  Example: Cygwin gcc, on _windows_, writes 1 byte with OP's code.

Comment: Wow I feel very dumb right now. This fixes the issue and makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: I'd say it's more of a C runtime library issue than a compiler issue.